# Text jumps down in UITextField when editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm having a weird issue here.
Textfield’s bounds change when textfield becomes firstResponder and rolls back when resigns.

In other words, when I tap on the textfield to change the text, **text jumps down**.

I'm using system font with size 16. I have two different `UITextField`s, one with border and one without border but same happens to both of them.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it ?

[image: This is what happens]

**Update**

So after testing for a few days, I realized that this issue only happens on **iOS 10**

Comment: Calling invalidateIntristicContentSize might fix the problem

Comment: can you post a screentshot?

Comment: Yes I just added a gif @BurhanuddinSunelwala

Comment: It did not work, any other suggestions? @farzadshbfn

Comment: why are you using two text fields? are you using them one top of other?

Comment: Two text fields in two different View Controllers, have the same issue. I'm not using them on top of each other and their not related in any way. @BurhanuddinSunelwala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my experience this is an iOS 10 bug and the only way to resolve in my case was to make the height of my `UITextField` to equal the text height (based on font type, you need different relations between font size and `UITextField` height).

For example if the height of the `UITextField` is 30 points the system font size must be 20.
Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Cool!.You're Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. (Spent more than 1 day for this issue).

In my case, the solution is that turn off `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` of `UIViewController`.